# Will it ambigram?

Tags: code-golf

First challenge!

## What is an ambigram?

Ambigrams are word(s) that read the same word(s) or another word given a certain transformation and possibly stylistic alterations.

Example:

[image]

That's an example of a rotational ambigram; it reads the same word, even when flipped around.

## The Challenge

You are to create a function, program, etc. that can detect whether a given input (consisting of only a-zA-Z chars) is a natural symmetric ambigram (an ambigram that reads the same word without significant artistic alteration given a transformation). You can compete in one or more of the following categories:

### Rotational

Examples: `I`, `O`, `ae`, `AV`, `pod`

#### Transformation table (both ways)

```
a  e/D
b  q
d  p/P
h  y
l  l
m  w
n  u/U
o  o/O/G/Q
s  s/S
t  t
x  x/X
z  z/Z
A  v/V
B  E
D  G
H  H
I  I
M  W
N  N
```

Output truesy or falsy value.

### Reflectional (Vertical Line)

Examples: `wow`, `mom`, `HOH`

#### Chars to match

```
b/d i j l m n o p/q s/z t u v w x y A B/E G/D H I M O Q S/Z T U V W X Y
```

Output truthy or falsy value.

### Reflectional (Horizontal Line)

Examples: `XOD`, `KEK`, `BED`

#### Chars to match

```
a l o t x B C D E H I K O X
```

Output truthy or falsy value.

### Totem

Examples:

```
x  n  O
o  u  H
x  M  I
      O
```

#### Chars to match

```
A H I M O T U V W X Y i l m n o t u v w x y
```

Output truthy or falsy value.

### Any (bonus of -50%)

This code should either output the type(s) of ambigram(s) that the input could possibly be (if the input is an ambigram) or a falsy value (if the input is not an ambigram).

## Code rules

- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- Input is case-sensitive. This means that AV would count, but aV would not count as a rotational ambigram.
- An input of zero length is considered to be a natural symmetric ambigram.
- Make sure to write your header as: `# Division, Language, Byte-Count`.
- This is code-golf! You know what that means.

Comment: Consolas is a Microsoft font and not present on all devices. Please include a list of all rotational and reflectional characters in your specification.

Comment: I would include a table of characters and their horizontal and vertical reflections.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Correction: "ambigram," not "anagram." To everyone: I've corrected some stuff. Should be good?

Comment: To qualify for the bonus, what exactly does the submission have to return?

Comment: What is "*totem*"?

Comment: I still don't get the totem. I *think* what it means is that if written vertically it will have a vertical line of symmetry, but it certainly isn't made clear. It needs to be clarified in the spec before I will cast a reopen vote.

Comment: Clarified totem. Also clarified bonus.

Comment: Why are `D` and `G` in multiple groups in the rotational symmetry?
Shouldn't they just be in one?

Comment: @TFeld 'D' can become an 'a' or 'g' when rotated. 'G' can become a 'D' or 'O' when rotated. It takes minimal modification to do so.

Comment: @molarmanful I get it now :)
Shouldn't `T` be included in the `Totem` though?

Comment: Nice challenge. Could plese explain the rotion `a` `D`? (in any font they seems different enough)

Comment: Does `bod` match the requirements for vertical reflection?

Comment: What is that example image supposed to say?

Comment: @ThePopMatchine Molarmanful. It's one of my earliest/not-the-best ambigram. Of course, I have a gallery [here](http://molarmanful.com/ambigrams) with better ones (probably).

Comment: @TFeld Nice catch! Edited.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 258 bytes (<s>622</s> <s>567</s> <s>543</s> 516-50%)

Here's my attempt at an answer.

```
R=dict(zip(list('abdhlmnostxzABDHIMN'),'eD q pP y l w uU oOGQ sS t xX zZ vV E G H I W N'.split()))
V='ijlmnotuvwxyAHIMOQTUVWXY'
W=dict(b='d',p='q',s='z',B='E',G='D',S='Z')
H='lotxBCDEHIKOX'
T='AHIMOTUVWXYilmnotuvwxy'
s=raw_input()
r=v=h=t=1
for i,j in R.items():
 for c in j:R[c]=R.get(c,'')+i
for i,j in W.items():
 for c in j:W[c]=W.get(c,'')+i
for i in range(len(s)):
 c,l=s[i],s[-i-1]
 r&=(c in R and l in R[c])
 v&=c in V or(c in W and l in W[c])
 h&=(c in H)+(l in H)>1
 t&=c in T
print 'R'*r+'V'*v+'H'*h+'T'*t
```

Prints the possible types of ambigrams, or `0` if no ambigrams are possible.

`RVHT` for rotational, vertical, horizontal and totem respectively.

Comment: Should be able to do `not (x and y)` -> `(x)+(y)>1` where `x` and `y` are boolean statements. You should also be able to define dictionaries like: `R=dict(a='ed',b='q'...)`. I believe the empty string should count as a falsy value so you can drop the `or 0`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks!
Though it seems should be `(x)+(y)<2` or else it's just an `and`

Comment: You're right, and I did [some more golfing](http://pastebin.com/F2QCDPJ7), but I've just noticed that I think your calculation for vertical reflection is incorrect. I think you need to use a dictionary again, and for example it should match `bod` I think (I will ask OP though)

Comment: save 34 chars: R=dict(zip(list('abdhlmnostxzABDHIMN'),'eD q pP y l w uU oOGQ sS t xX zZ vV E G H I W N'.split()))

Comment: You can save 6 bytes by removing the spaces in `H = 'lotxBCDEHIKOX'` and the next two lines, and 4 more by removing spaces between `if` and `(`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks, I fixed the vertical reflection

Answer (score 1):

## All, Ruby, 289 - 50% = 144.5 bytes

```
i=gets.chop;s=i.tr('ijlmnotuvwxyAHIMOQTUVWXY','').tr'bpsBGS','dqzEDZ';t=i.tr'eDqpPylwuUOGQStXZvVEGHIWN','aabddhlmnnooostxzAABDHIMN';o=(i.tr('alotxBCDEHIKOX','')=='' ? 'V':'')+(s==s.reverse ? 'H':'')+(i.tr('AHIMOUVWXYilmnotuvwxy','')=='' ? 'T':'')+(t==t.reverse ? 'R':'');puts o=='' ? 1<0:o
```

This seems too long...